# pull working, push not working for 1und1 git service

Tags: git

I am using 1und1.de service for GIT they offer. Now I am setting it up and I pulled the changes to my local computer from there with the command git pull ssh://.........

but when I tried to to git push ssh://...... I received a lot of errors:

```
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: by default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree incosistent

Auto packing the repository for optimum performance.remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git  reset --hard' to match

remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error:
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' Configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you arranged to update its work tree to match waht you pushed in some other way.

remote: error: to sqelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
! [remote_rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://........'
```

Comment: How did you setup the repo? Did they do it for you?

Comment: no, I did, I just typed in the: git init command, do you think I should have done something like git init --bare.. or maybe I need to configure it to accept git push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of Git repository. A *bare* repository is usually called `foo.git` and doesn't have a working tree, just Git's internal files. A *non-bare* repository is a working tree (that is, a directory with all the files) which also contains a directory named `.git`. As the error message explains, pushing into a non-bare repository is usually a bad idea, because when you do that the working tree becomes out of date against the repository.

When you're hosting a repository for people to pull from and push into, you almost always want a bare repository. It seems like in this case you've created a non-bare repository. Since you don't give any details of how you created the repository, I can't tell you what you did wrong, but you can create a bare repository in one of two ways:

1. From the directory where you want to create the repository, issue `git clone --bare path/to/original.git`. That will clone the source to a bare repository `original.git` inside the directory you're in.
2. From the directory where you want to create the repository, issue `git init --bare foo.git`. This will create an empty bare repository `foo.git` inside the directory you're in.

There are more things you can do, but they're the easiest to get right. Issuing `git config --set core.bare false` inside an existing repository will make Git think it's a bare repository from then on, but you have to delete the working tree yourself, and you should probably rename the repository from `.git` to `foo.git`.

Comment: I want the existing git remote to change to bare repo but I am afraid I might do something wrong and change the files in my server

Comment: If your local copy is up to date, just delete the work tree on the server and start again.

Comment: the work tree is deleted by deleting the .git file?

Comment: The work tree is deleted by deleting the directory that contains the `.git` directory: that is, the one with all your files in.

Comment: thank you I am going to detele it now, and initiate a new git --bare repo

Answer (score 1):

When you are setting up a repository that you intend to push to, set it up as a `bare` repository:

```
git init --bare
```

Though it is technically possible to push to a repo with working directory, it is too much of a headache, and in this case, you don't even want that.

Just recreate the repo as a bare one or create a bare one from it (`git clone --bare /path/to/repo`)

Comment: I want the existing git remote to change to bare repo but I am afraid I might do something wrong and change the files in my server

Comment: @TooCooL - Clone the repo to a different locations like so `git clone --bare /path/to/repo`. See if it works. And then replace the old one

Comment: Is it possible to delete the .git file in the server to delete everything from this git repo, then run the command git init --bare and add the files to git tracking, I dont care about the commits because I dont have commits, just one when I started it.